# Using Two JCalender for SWT Application

Tags: java, desktop-application, jcalendar

http://i41.tinypic.com/344bo77.png

From Day Cannot be Today's Date or Later.
To Date cannot be maximum than today's date & From Date.

I have to set the code in such a way that after selecting a particular date on From date, To date will be enabled.

Sample code will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for your date calculations. With regards to enabling and disabling your date values, Swing components have `setEnabled()` methods which you can use to either disable or enable the component.

That being said, you did not specify what have you tried... and are requesting code... I doubt those are two steps in the right direction for using this site...

Comment: I have tried JCalender using Netbeans. How can i get the date. from the event. I have tied a lot of code no use..! :(

Comment: You could try take a look here: http://jcalendarbutton.sourceforge.net/netbeans.html

Comment: Thanks Buddy..! U helped A lot but i have figured out using Jcalender itself..!